# How to save a Spark (scala) Mllib model to ONNX

Tags: scala, apache-spark, onnx

I trained a Spark MLLib pipeline, I want to save one of it's trained stages (a LightGBM classifier) into ONNX. The training function is like this one:

```
def trainModel(trainingDataFrame: DataFrame): Transformer = {
        val vectorAssember = createVectorAssembler(featureColumnsNames, assembledVectorColumnName)
        val classifier = createLightGBMClassifier(lightGBMArguments)
        val evaluator = new BinaryClassificationEvaluator()
        val pipeline = createPipeline(vectorAssember, classifier)
        
        val crossValidator = createCrossValidator(crossValidatorArguments, pipeline, evaluator)
        val trainedPipeline = crossValidator.fit(trainingDataFrame)

        val bestPipeline: PipelineModel = trainedPipeline.bestModel.asInstanceOf[PipelineModel]
        val bestClassifier = bestPipeline.stages(1)

        bestClassifier
    }
```

Given that, how could I export the resulting bestClassifier for ONNX? I have seen [examples in Python](https://github.com/onnx/onnxmltools/blob/main/onnxmltools/convert/sparkml/README.md), but not in Scala. I could see how to load trained ONNX models for inference in Spark Scala, but can find how to use export a trained one.

Any help?